# View not updating for modified child of ObservedObject

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to build a `View` which a list of children of an object, and I want those children to be modifiable. The data changes, but the view doesn't react.

Here is the stripped down example.

```swift
class ObjectOne: ObservableObject {
    
   @Published var children: [ObjectTwo]
    
    init() {
        self.children = []
    }
}
```

```
class ObjectTwo: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var value: Value
    var id = UUID()
    
    init(value: Value) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var object: ObjectOne = ObjectOne()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                self.object.children.append(ObjectTwo(value: .one))
            } label: {
                Text("Add Object")
            }
            Text("Objects:")
            ForEach(self.object.children, id: \.id) { object in
                HStack {
                    Text(String(object.value.rawValue))
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        if object.value == .one {
                            object.value = .two
                        } else {
                            object.value = .one
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Toggle")
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Adding objects works and the list updates, but modifying the `value` of the `ObjectTwo` doesn't update the view.

Comment: Every ObservableObject needs a wrapper in a SwiftUI view. There are workarounds with combine’s sink but this is just a very complex setup

Comment: one thing you can do is change `@ObservedObject` to `@StateObject`. Typically, you want to use `@ObservedObject` when another view creates the object and the current view is just using it. See here for reference: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject

Answer (score 0):

When you have nested `ObservableObject`, you need to manually tell them about upcoming changes. Try this, works for me.

```
Button {
    self.object.objectWillChange.send()  // <--- here
    if object.value == .one {
        object.value = .two
    } else {
        object.value = .one
    }
} label: {
    Text("Toggle")
}
```

I recommend you use a `struct` for your `ObjectTwo`, it is easier to use (with some minor code change) and IMHO common practice.

For example, you could use this:

```
struct ObjectTwo: Identifiable {  // <-- here
    var value: Value
    var id = UUID()
    
    init(value: Value) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var objectModel = ObjectOne() // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                objectModel.children.append(ObjectTwo(value: .one))
            } label: {
                Text("Add Object")
            }
            Text("Objects:")
            ForEach($objectModel.children, id: \.id) { $object in  // <-- here
                HStack {
                    Text(String(object.value.rawValue))
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        if object.value == .one {
                            object.value = .two
                        } else {
                            object.value = .one
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Toggle")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift is designed to use value types instead of objects (to prevent consistency bugs) see [Choosing Between Structures and Classes - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing-between-structures-and-classes). SwiftUI exploits these value semantics in its implementation of dependency and change tracking, if you use objects you'll lose these features. Generally in SwiftUI we can get away with one store object (that persists/syncs model data) and use model structs so we can take advantage of SwiftUI's dependency tracking of value types and `@Binding` for write access, e.g.

```
class Store: ObservableObject {
   static var shared = Store()
   static var preview = Store(preview: true)

   @Published var items: [Item] = []
    
    init(preview: Bool) {
        if (preview) {
            items = [Item(text: "Test")]
        }
        else {
           load()
        }
    }

    func load(){}
    func save(){}
}

class Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    @Published title = ""
    
    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
            .environmentObject(Store.shared)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store
    var body: View {
        List($store.items) { $item in
            TextField("Title", text: $item.title)
        }
     }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
        .environmentObject(Store.preview)
    }
}
```